# Is it perpendicular each other between r component vector and $\theta$ component vector of the magnetic field vector?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, vectors, vector-fields, magnetostatics

Currently I'm very new to static magnetic field.

> [image]
>
> Cited from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Transformation-of-the-magnetic-field-intensity-from-polar-to-Cartesian-coordinates-with-th_fig2_264698002)

As I see many diagrams of magnetic field, I found that each $H_{\theta}$ and $H_{r}$ are seemingly perpendicular each other.

Is it actually perpendicular?

Which website should I refer?

Comment: They are perpendicular by definition. $\hat{\theta}$ is defined to be perpendicular to the unit vector $\hat{r}$.

Comment: I see! You can get reputation points as you wrote the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at a vector decomposed in polar coordinates.  This is an orthogonal coordinate system where at each point the tangent vectors to the independent coordinate curves are orthogonal.  There is a general procedure for constructing coordinates in this way.  I'd recommend looking the procedure up in any text on advanced calculus for more details.  The same would hold for spherical coordinates and the $r$, $\theta$, and $\phi$ directions.

Answer (score 1):

$H_{\theta}$ and $H_r$ are perpendicular by definition. $\hat{θ}$ is defined to be perpendicular to the unit vector $\hat{r}$.